# Storing text into a String using jSoup

Tags: java, html, string, jsoup

I'm trying to understand how to use htmlUnit and jSoup together and have been successful in understanding the basics. However, I'm trying to store text from a specific webpage into a string but when I try to do this, it only returns a single line rather than the whole text.

I know the code I've written works as I when I print out p.text, it returns the whole text stored within the website.

```
private static String getText() {
    try {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.gov.uk/government/policies/brexit");
        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors = page.getAnchors();
        HtmlPage page1 = anchors.get(18).click();
        String url = page1.getUrl().toString();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("div[class=govspeak] p");
        for (Element p : paragraphs)
            System.out.println(p.text());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.getLogger(HTMLParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

When I introduce the notion of a string to store the text from p.text, it only returns a single line rather than the whole text.

```
private static String getText() {
    String text = "";
    try {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.gov.uk/government/policies/brexit");
        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors = page.getAnchors();
        HtmlPage page1 = anchors.get(18).click();
        String url = page1.getUrl().toString();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("div[class=govspeak] p");
        for (Element p : paragraphs)
            text=p.text();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.getLogger(HTMLParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Ultimately, all I want to do is store the whole text into a string. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (Element p : paragraphs)
        text+=p.text(); // Append the text.
```

In your code, you are overwriting the values of variable text. That's why only last line is returned by the function.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the correct method of me fixing my problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String text = doc.text();
```

That's basically it. Due to the fact that JSoup is already taking care of cleaning all the html tags from the text, you can use the `doc.text()` and you'll receive the content of the whole page cleaned from html tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a strange idea to use the HtmlUnit result as starting point for jSoup. There a various drawbacks of your approach (e.g. think about cookies). And of course HtmlUnit had parsed the html code already; you will do the work twice.

I hope this code will fulfill your requirements without jSoup.

```
private static String getText() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.gov.uk/government/policies/brexit");
        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors = page.getAnchors();
        HtmlPage page1 = anchors.get(18).click();
        DomNodeList<DomNode> paragraphs = page1.querySelectorAll("div[class=govspeak] p");
        for (DomNode p : paragraphs) {
            text.append(p.asText());
        }
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```